# Simple search gives 404 page for results

Tags: search, http-status-code-404

EE2.9.2. Simple search form:

```
    {exp:search:simple_form channel="home|about|network|community|pages|people|news" search_in="entries" result_page="search/results" form_id="search_form"}
    <input type="text" name="keywords" id="search" placeholder="Search" />
    {/exp:search:simple_form}
```

Results page:

```
            <h2>Search results for &ldquo;{exp:search:keywords}&rdquo;</h2>
              <p>Your search returned {exp:search:total_results} results.</p>
                {exp:search:search_results}
                {if count == 1} 
                {/if}
                    <h3><a href="{if page_url}{page_url}{if:else}{auto_path}{/if}">{title}</a> - {channel_id}</h3>
                        <!-- page_url is {page_url} entry_id is {entry_id} -->
                        <p>{excerpt}<br><strong><a href="{if page_url}{page_url}{if:else}{auto_path}{/if}">Read more&rarr;</a></strong></p>
                {/exp:search:search_results}
```

[image: Here's what output looks like]

The number 2 is the channel ID - it's not giving me results across channels either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, y'all. It was an error in my code. Don't wrap a channel entries tag around search results, it doesn't like that!